# rsync with non-standard port and multifactor 2FA with Google Authenticator

Tags: centos, ssh, rsync

SSH to my server works. But I've enabled Multifactor authentication with Google Authenticator. So during the process of SSH, it asks for my verification code.

Issue now is I want to rsync to this server from a server located in another country. I'm trying this command:

```
rsync -av --progress  -e "ssh -2 -p 2299" origin.txt myuser@9.9.9.9:/pat/to/destination/
```

Where the non-standard port is `2299` and the IP of the destination server is `9.9.9.9` in this illustrative example. Challenge is that SSH is not asking me for my verification code. So rsync fails with a message like this:

```
ssh: connect to host 9.9.9.9 port 2299: Connection timed out
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

Any ideas how I can enable rsync to also ask me the verification code so that this works?

Comment: A work-around I've used in the past is to configure a grace period where new connections established with 30s after a successful 2FA login from the same IP & user would not require 2FA again.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose there's that option while setting up the authentication, but that leads to a rushed stressful time for every rsync, and in any case it doesn't solve the issue of doing rsync with cron jobs as I may not be around to manually do that. In this case, is there a workaround that if I specify a command attribute, then the 2FA verification should NOT occur?

Comment: Or, some program on the local server that's CHMODed to only the main user on the server and can be called from rsync command at run time to do auto-generate the verification code and pass it programmatically?